# What exactly does this symbol mean, and what is it called? It looks like the any function $f(x)$, but with a line drawn over the entire thing.

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

I've been seeing it a lot recently, and I'm not sure what it's called, and I've searching on google things like "$f(x)$ with a bar over it". Even just a name for it would be helpful [$f(x)$ with a line over the entire thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKVOL.png)

I'm tagging complex numbers because that's where I first saw the symbol

Comment: The overline denotes complex conjugation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  It’s called a [vinculum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vinculum.html?simple=True)

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overline symbol is called a [vinculum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vinculum.html?simple=True).

It groups symbols together and has several uses in mathematics,

including square roots, repeating decimals, and logical negation.

In the context of complex numbers, it denotes the complex conjugate.