# Find digits x and y such that the number $\overline{25xy5}$ is divisible by 3 and 7.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have some problems with the following task:
Find digits x and y such that the number $\overline{25xy5}$ is divisible by 3 and 7.

So far, I have come up with this solution:

$$
\begin{cases}
2+5+x+y+5=3p,\ p \in\mathbb{Z+}  \\ 
25xy-10=7q, \ q \in\mathbb{Z+}
\end{cases} 
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
2+5+x+y+5=3p,\ p \in\mathbb{Z+}  \\ 
2500+10x+y-10=7q, \ q \in\mathbb{Z+}
\end{cases} 
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=3p-12,\ p \in\mathbb{Z+}  \\ 
10x+y=7q-2490, \ q \in\mathbb{Z+}
\end{cases} 
$$

And the problem is that I don't know if I am on the right way to the solution and what to do with the parameters **p** and **q**.

Comment: Since $2+5+5\equiv 0\pmod 3$, you see that $x+y\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and you can get a similar relation $\pmod 7$.  Ultimately, not a lot of pairs to check.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $7|abctuv\iff 7|tuv-abd$, so you're looking for $7\mid xy-2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: are you really giving people hints about the arcane secret that $1001 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$??? Oops! I gave it away $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Of course I meant $abc$ where I typed $abd$

Comment: Is it standard to use the [vinculum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634586/what-exactly-does-this-symbol-mean-and-what-is-it-called-it-looks-like-the-any) $\overline{abc}$ to indicate $100a+10b+c$?

Comment: By [congruence laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) the divisibility holds $\!\iff\! \overline{xy}\equiv_7 2,\ \overline{xy}\equiv_3 0\!\iff\! \overline{xy}\equiv_{21} 9\,$ by [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242). $\ \ $

Comment: Unlike the proposed duplicate question, OP here did not write congruences ("what to do with **p** and **q**?")

Comment: **Or** w/o CRT: $\bmod 21\!:\ \color{#c00}{10\equiv\frac{\!-\!1}2}\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{25}[\color{#c00}{10}^3]\equiv \color{#0a0}4\left[\color{#c00}{\frac{\!\!-1}2}\!\right]^2\!10\equiv \color{#0af}{10},\,$ hence$\,0\equiv \overline{\color{#0a0}{25}xy5}\equiv \color{#0af}{10}\!+\!\color{#c00}{10}\overline{xy}\!+\!5\!\iff\!$ $\color{#c00}{\frac{\!-\!1}2}\overline{xy}\equiv -15\!\iff\overline{xy}\equiv 30\equiv 9\ \ $

Comment: The $\rm\color{#c00}{prior}$ method is essentially the idea behind the [reverse divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4417381/242) for $21.\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\overline{25xy5} =25005 + \overline{xy0}\underset7\equiv 1+10\cdot \overline{xy}\underset7\equiv 1+3\cdot \overline{xy}.$$

Hence $$1+3\cdot \overline{xy} \underset7\equiv 0,$$

or $$\overline{xy}\underset7\equiv 2.$$

Also we have that $$2+5+x+y+5 \underset3\equiv 0,$$

so $$x+y \underset3\equiv 0.$$

From here you just probably try all numbers of the form $7k+2$ and check if sum of two digits is divisible by $3$. From $02$, $09$, $16$, $23$, $30$, $37$, $44$, $51$, $58$, $65$, $72$, $79$, $86$, $93$ only $$09, 30, 51, 72, 93$$ are good.

Comment: $\overline{xy}\equiv_7 2,\ \overline{xy}\equiv_3 0\!\iff\! \overline{xy}\equiv_{21} 9\,$ by CRT. $\ \ $

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).